# How to use socket.io to communicate with AngularJS in a MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, mean-stack

Working on a MEAN app. Have angular in the front and it's working fine. Express in the back is working fine as well. I am coming to the point of needing to rely on mongoose for handling the MongoDB stuff.

Ultimately, I'd like to load up the data stored in my `db` in some list using Angular on the front end. I've heard socket.io is good for this sort of thing, and it seems like it should be easy to use.

I found this repo and I've been trying for the past few hours to make it work: https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

Unfortunately, the README is pretty sparse on how *exactly* to get this to work, and the issues aren't helpful either.

**Problem:** I can't communicate at all using `socket.emit()` or `socket.on()` or any of the wonderful things socket.io is supposed to do. Just a sad blinking cursor in my terminal.

**server.js**

```
var port = 8080;
io = require('socket.io');
http = require('http');
server = http.createServer(app);
io = io.listen(server);
server.listen(port);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('send:garbage',function (data) {
        console.log('omg it finally worked');
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('MyCtrl',[]).controller('MyController',function($scope,mySocket) {

    // triggered by a button press (prints fine to browser console)
    $scope.runTest = function () {
        mySocket.emit('send:garbage', { 'my' : 'data' });
        console.log('what the shit');
    };
}
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp',[
    ...
    'btford.socket-io',
    ...
]);
```

Crazy thing is, I've cloned a few more tutorials and they work like a charm out of the box. Any thoughts on why this might be happening, and whether there's a simpler way to communicate between Angular and the back end?

---

**EDIT - BUG FOUND!**

Apparently this repo just doesn't work with socket.io v1.0+. I downloaded a working tutorial from [chariot solutions](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/getting-chatty-angular-socket-io-nodeexpress-bootstrap/) that uses `angular-socket-io`. It had socket.io v0.9.17, and worked fine. When I `npm update socket.io --save`d, and updated to v1.2.0, socket communication broke.

---

**EDIT 2 - giving up and just using Angular's `$http`, which is great**

Further hacking went nowhere, and then I just tried using Angular's $http service to accomplish the same thing. And it's incredibly simple.

Scotch.io has an [excellent tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) on using it to set up a simple to-do app. This fixed my front-end to back-end woes.

Comment: [It seems you haven't included the `btford.socket-io` dependency in your angular app module](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io#using-your-socket-instance). Also check the console log. Angular's error logs are pretty helpful and take you to the error.angular website for further help.

Comment: that'd be great if it was that easy. The module is included in my app, and I've edited the question to reflect that. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any error messages in either my terminal window or my browser's console. Everything works, except for the socket.io part.

Comment: How about connecting through plain [socket.io](http://socket.io/) (and not the btford module)? Does that work?

Comment: gave up on trying to shoehorn socket.io into my app and went with Angular's `$http` instead. Works like a charm. Thanks for the input!

Comment: When I do an $http PUT call for example and then have a socket reply, the PUT is constantly pending and crashes. It never gets a reply even if I put res.status(200)